# Limit SQL join when using CodeIgniter active record class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting a product listing. Each product may have 1 or more image, I only want to return the first image.

```
$this->db->select('p.product_id, p.product_name i.img_name, i.img_ext');    
$this->db->join('products_images i', 'i.product_id = p.product_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get('products p');
```

Is there anyway to limit the db->join to 1 record using the CI active record class?

Comment: silly question I know, but have you tried chaining in a $this->db->limit() call?

Comment: $this->db->limit() only works for the get()

Comment: Build a query string for each product and concatenate them with UNION ALL, it's a fairly efficient for what you're trying to do, you'll need 2 queries in total. I can find the article somewhere if you want it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$this->db->limit(1);` before calling `$this->db->get('products p');`. See the docs at [ellislab.com](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html): search the page for **limit**.

EDIT: I misread the fact that you were trying to apply the LIMIT to the internal JOIN statement.

No. Since you can not do a LIMIT on an internal JOIN statement in regular SQL you can not do it with Code Igniter's ActiveRecord class.

Comment: That would limit the number of products returned. I want to limit the number of results returned on the $this->db->join(products_images i) call

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `$this->db->group_by` with a `left` join:

```
$this->db->select('products.id, products.product_name, products_images.img_name, products_images.img_ext');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('products_images', 'products_images.product_id = products.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('products.id'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

This should give you results by `products.id` (without repetition of products), with the first matching record from `products_images` joined to each result row. If there's no matching row from the joined table (i.e. if an image is missing) you'll get null values for the products_images fields but will still see a result from the `products` table.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to give consistent results.  `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function in the `SELECT` or `HAVING` clause is nonsensical SQL.  The image returned is going to be completely arbitrary, and this SQL will only work with MySQL (most RDBMSs will reject this as a syntax error).

Comment: @BaconBits - Thanks for the expanded answer below. I know this is not the ideal forum for Q&A, but RE: your comment "in fact, you don't really want to" - are you saying the only way to do this is without a join? i.e. query products then iterate the results and query the images table for each item? Seems very expensive!

Comment: @BaconBits Scrap that, found a solution [here](http://murrayhopkins.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/mysql-left-join-on-last-or-first-record-in-the-right-table/). Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Femi's answer:

There's no good way to limit the `JOIN`, and, in fact, you don't really want to.  Assuming both `products_image.product_id` and `products.id` have indexes (and they absolutely should if you're going to join against them repeatedly) when the database engine does a join, it uses the indexes to determine what rows it needs to fetch.  Then the engine uses the results to determine where on the disk to find the records it needs.  If you

You should be able to see the difference by running these SQL statements:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, i.img_name, i.img_ext
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_images i
    ON i.product_id = p.product_id
```

as opposed to:

```
EXPLAIN  
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, i.img_name, i.img_ext
FROM (SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products) p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT img_name, img_ext FROM products_images) i
    ON i.product_id = p.product_id
```

The first query should have an index, the second one will not.  There should be a performance difference if there's a significant number of rows the the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue too the way I solved it was iterating over the results and removing the current object if the product_id had existed in a previous one. Create a array, push the product_id's to it while checking if they are repeats.

```
$product_array = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($result as $r){

    if(in_array($r->product_id,$product_array)){
        unset($result[$i]);
    }else{
        array_push($product_array,$r->product_id);
    }
    $i++;

} 

$result = array_values($result); //re-index result array
```

Now $result is what we want