# Retrieve only one row of comment

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a site developed in codeigniter where I want to retrieve comment of a specific tee.
I have a table tee like that:

```
- id
- user_id
- name
- created
- modified
```

And the table tee_comments like that:

```
- id
- user_id
- tee_id
- created
- modified
```

I have done this query:

```
 $this->db->select('*,tee.id as id,tee.created as created, tee_comments.id as tee_comments_id, tee_comments.created as tee_comments_created, tee_comments.modified as tee_comments_modified');
    $this->db->from('tee');
    $this->db->join('tee_comments', 'tee_comments.tee_id = tee.id','left outer');
    $this->db->order_by("tee.created", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

With this query I retrieve two rows of tee because I have two comments in that tee.

My goal is to retrieve only one row where inside there is an array of comment like:

```
tee{
  id,
  name,
  created,
  modified
  comment{
     [0]
         id,
         tee_id,
         comment,
         created,
         modified
     [1]
         id,
         tee_id,
         comment,
         created,
         modified
  }
}
```

I have tried into the join:
- left
- right
- left outer
- right outer

But doesn't  solve the problem, is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: A database query retrieves rows from a (combination of) table(s). If you want a nested structure, you would have to generate that yourself in php.

Comment: You'll have to manually aggregate the comment data with the corresponding tee record

Comment: Your question states you want only 1 row of comment, but what you want to achieve includes multiple comments?

Comment: @jeroen he's using CI, it returns a "nested structure"

Comment: @SpYk3HH We might be using different definitions of `nested structures`; it returns rows with information but these rows do not contain sub-rows of information (the comments...) like the OP needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love CodeIgniter! I use it constantly! You have 2 really simple options here:

One way would be to use `limit`.

```
$this->db->select('*,tee.id as id,tee.created as created, tee_comments.id as tee_comments_id, tee_comments.created as tee_comments_created, tee_comments.modified as tee_comments_modified');
$this->db->join('tee_comments', 'tee_comments.tee_id = tee.id','left outer');
$this->db->order_by("tee.created", "desc");
$query = $this->db->limit(1)->get('tee');
```

---

Another way is to get first item in `results Array`

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$results = $query->result(); // gets return as an array
$row = $results[0]; // will be first row in results array
```

Keep in mind tho, `$row` will return as a `object(stdClass)` meaning you'll have to retrieve things from it like `$row->column_name`.

A handy little snippet I like to use after a call is below. It makes the row `Object`'s `Array`'s instead.

```
$results = $db->get('tee')->result(); // snippet comes after you have result array
// snippet here
foreach ($r as $k => $v) { $results[$k] = array(); foreach ($v as $kk => $vv) { $results[$k][$kk] = $vv != "NULL" ? trim($vv) : ""; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->db->limit(1)` to retrieve a single record.

According to the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086767/update-with-limit-1-in-codeigniter-use-active-record), you may need to put the limit statement before the select:

```
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->select('*,tee.id as id,tee.created as created, tee_comments.id as tee_comments_id, tee_comments.created as tee_comments_created, tee_comments.modified as tee_comments_modified');
$this->db->from('tee');
```

Comment: but I have to retrieve all tee with their comment for example I know that limit can retrieve only one record but isn't this case

Comment: Hm, in that case it might not be possible. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105451/limit-sql-join-when-using-codeigniter-active-record-class

Answer (score 0):

Option one:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++)
{
 $data = $records[$i];
 // work with date.
 if($i == 1)
   break;
}
```

Option two:
just assign the first row to var.

```
$row = $records['tee']['comment'][0];
```